# Recuperate variable from an other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to recuperate variable "idl" in the function remote i have use window.var but that's not work.
there is my code.

```
function stbStatus(stbInfo){
$.post(
        'indexFunctions.php',
        {
            stbInfo : stbInfo
        },
                    function(data){
                        $('#screenshot').html(data);
                        $('#refresh').click({param:status},screenshotRefresh);
                        $('form').click(function() {
                         window.idl = this.id;
                        ({param:status},remote);
                         });

                    }

                );
            }
        );
    },
    'json'
);}
```

Function Remote:

```
function remote(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html').css('cursor','wait');
    var key = $("#"+window.idl).attr('class');
        $.get(
            'indexFunctions.php',
            {
                keyName: key
            },
            function(){
                if (key!="KEY_POWER" && key!="RESET")
                    screenshotRefresh(event);}
```

Please help me thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `$('#refresh').click({param:status},screenshotRefresh);` what is this code suppose to do?

Comment: hello,thank you for your answer refresh is a button that will call the function screenshotRefresh.this function will load an image form the server and display it into html

Comment: strange way to call a function can you provide me with some example of this sintax?

Comment: thank you i have resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Because of the async nature of the ajax you need to call the remote function inside the success function of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

there is the code of function screenshotrefresh

```
function screenshotRefresh(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html').css('cursor','wait');
    $.post(
        'indexFunctions.php',
        {
            screenshot : event.data.param
            },
            function(img){
            $('html').css('cursor','default');
                $('#screenshot').html(img);
            }
        );
    }
```